# How to secure private class field with PHP OO?

Tags: php, oop, private

How to secure private class field with PHP OO? I don't want to make private class field $a public, but when I do something like that:

```
class Hidden {
   private $a = 'Very important, hidden variable';
   protected $b = 'secret';
}
$obj = new Hidden();
$c = (array)$obj;
print_r($c);
```

$a is available for everybody:

```
Array ( [Hiddena] => Very important, hidden variable [*b] => secret )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could elaborate on your concerns and give an example of a scenario where an attacker could exploit this condition in your specific case, since if anybody is able to inject PHP code into your application, you have a big problem anyway.

Access modifiers in OOP are about encapsulation, not actual security. With `private`, you prevent other developers from unintentionally accessing the fields, not malicious code or potential attackers.

For this reason, `SecureString` was introduced in C#. To emulate something like this in PHP, you'd have to store an encrypted value in `$a` and keep the key in a "secure" location which nobody who has the power to execute `print_r` or `var_dump` can access (file, DB). But then again, anybody who can `print_r` your object, can probably do `file_get_contents` on the key file.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How, then, to write api, in such a way to hide certain information to the consumer of the api?

Comment: What kind of API is this? What field value is so secret that the users of your library shouldn't see it?